# PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks not getting fired

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

I built the authentication feature of an app using Firebase's phone number verification. I tested and everything worked fine for multiple test devices.

However, I wiped my test phone, rebooted and decided to test the same app again. This time, I noticed that **NONE** of the methods in [`OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks) were being fired.

This was particularly surprising because I had not edited the codebase at all. I placed logs at the start of each of the three methods and none of them got called. In essence, `OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks` is not working.

Here's a snippet of my OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks initialization:

```
onVerificationStateChangedCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
            Log.d(TAG, "verification completed "+ phoneAuthCredential.toString());
            // some stuff
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "verification failed "+ e.getMessage());
            // some stuff
        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String s, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Code sent "+ s);
            // some stuff
        }
    };
```

My logs are not picking up anything. Also, none of the methods in the callback are being executed.

**Extra steps taken:**

- I checked the Firebase dashboard to make sure I had not exceeded the free quota.
- I confirmed that phone number was still set as one of the sign-in methods.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key sentence in the entire question is:

> However, I wiped my test phone, rebooted and decided to test the same app again.

The [official documentation for Firebase phone-auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth) states that Google Play services of a device MUST be installed and up-to-date before the `verifyPhoneNumber` function can work. None of the callbacks were being fired because Google Play Services was either missing or outdated.

Another potential way to resolve this issue is to use timed requests or try-and-catch.

**NB:** I think it's quite odd that `OnVerificationFailed()` was not called due to this. Since most developers typically rely on these three callback methods for flow continuity, this might count as an issue.